# How do I mirror a monitor in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors

How do I mirror a monitor in Windows Vista?

I do not want to "extend" the desktop to the monitor, but I want the second monitor (a TV in this case) to be an exact copy of the main monitor.

Comment: Just press Windows+U !
There is no shorter way)

Answer (score 2):

Activate **Clone Mode**, depending on your graphics card:

**Intel GMA**

[image]

**ATI Radeon**

[image]

**NVIDIA GeForce**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open Control Panel > Windows Mobility Center.
Turn on Presenting.
Click Connect Display. The New Display Detected dialog box should appear.
Select Duplicate my desktop on all displays (mirrored).
Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

My friend was trying to do this not too long ago. The answer was **the graphics card's control panel**.

If you don't have it, you'll need to install newer drivers for your card, and make sure to install either **ATI Catalyst** or **nVidia Control Panel**, depending on your alignment.

This is, apparently, not possible through the inbuilt settings box.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done in Control Panel:

Goto adjusting screen resolution

Make sure your TV is also plugged in

It should give you 2 screen sample things, '1' and a smaller '2'.

See 'Multiple Displays:' and select 'Duplicate these displays'.

Should work. If you do not have this option, it's probably because of Vista. It's working on 7 for sure.

Comment: This option has existed since at least Windows XP (I'd say earlier than that, since Windows 98 really ushered in multimonitor support for Windows). It definitely will work in Vista.

Comment: It definitely did not work on Vista. I had to get to the graphics driver control panel to enable this. Only the "extend the dosktop..." option existed.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, in former versions (including Vista) it was possible to drag and drop on of the two monitor icons above the other in the standard monitor control panel.